# My tumblr theme content is overlapping with the sidebar

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr, overlap

I recently created a new tumblr and grabbed a theme, but after some modifications (mostly after adding a corner image), my tumblr posts began covering the sidebar.

To view the code I used, please [click here](http://beadofbrotherhood.tumblr.com). Right click and select "view page source". I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you add some screen shots of the overlap and info on the interface you are using to view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidebar div is fixed to the left, and your #posts div has a margin-left of zero. So they are both set to be aligned to the left of the page and since the sidebar is fixed, they overlap.

Setting the left margin of the #posts div to something like 400px will fix the problem (I tested this in the web inspector of my browser):

```
margin-left: 400px;
```